# Itô formula's proof

Tags: martingales, stochastic-integrals, variance, covariance

it's about the proof of the 
[Itô formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDrkL.png)

Here I give the [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci4Ca.png)
(I marked the lines with my issues in colours)

1. How do we use a/the usual stopping argument?
2. How do we use [Lemma 4.51](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7pne.png)?

2a) We use the **variance process** $[X]_s$ . Why is it possible to extend it to a *covariance* process $[X^i,X^j]$. (I can see that we have to consider more dimensions but why is it possible to do it that way?)

2b) And how does the Itô-formula exactly follow for result follow from the implication $(H^n ° X) \rightarrow (H°X)$ of Lemma 4.51?

2c) Are polynomials always predictable?

3. Why is $Y$ a semimartingale?

Comment: The stopping time argument is that you may consider $\tau_M$ to be constantly $M$ whenever the covariation surpasses $M$. Proving the result on $\tau_M$ and then letting $M\to\infty$ (using convergence theorems) proves the general case. It is called localization.

Comment: Please do not put links. Just directly put the content in the links into the question.

Comment: @Panda, many thanks for answering question 1!

Comment: @HHuang, how can I do this with pictures? Or are you saying I should type the proof instead of uploading the pictures?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. People on MSE prefer no links unless absolutely necessary.